# Asynchronous Web Page

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, web, web-deployment

Good afternoon, I want to know something about loading a web page asynchronously. I have a web page that has a log in and is loading after the log in, in about 10 secs (maybe a bit more). This web page is loading really slow because in a section of the page, it has a tree which is loaded from multiple queries to the server. Discarding the optimization of the queries, what I want to do is, load the page but without loading the tree. Rather than loading the tree, load a spinning wheel to symbolize that its loading. When the document ready event is triggered, start loading the tree. I want to know a procedure ( if there is one ) or if it is as simple as sticking the tree in the document ready function. Thank you

Comment: Unless i'm mistaken, you just described what the procedure is. show the spinner, then when everything else is loaded, load the tree.

Comment: There are [trees out there that already have this arrangement](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/treeview_suppliment.htm); check out one of those.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of fine-tuned example for an application I'm currently working on. It uses jQuery and AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    params = { var1 = 2, var2 = 4 };
    var checkStatus = function() {
        $.getJSON('index.php/loader/op_status', params, function(opc) {
            results = $.parseJSON(opc.results);
            percent = results.status;

            if (results.status != 100) {
                $('#loading-percentage .percentage').html(percent);
                setTimeout(checkStatus, 1000); // check every second for results
            } else {
                $(opk.keywords).insertAfter('#opc-results .kw-section .summary');
                $('#loading-percentage').remove();
            }
        }
    }
    checkStatus();
}
```

What this is doing is checking a status file and returning an integer which I use as a literal status percentage. If the percentage is < 100 then show a loading animation, otherwise load the finish content and remove the animation. The process is checked every second so you can get the most up-to-date status in real-time.

You can use this is as as a starting point but obviously you'll need to fine-tune this to your needs.